# Gulp-rev on multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, chef-infra, gulp

We have a number of production servers and recently introduced gulp to building our frontend of our app and away from Rails asset pipeline.

So far so good except the Rails asset pipeline used to magically sync the cache busting between the servers and load balancer worked nicely. This is not the case with `gulp-rev` which builds on each individual server and randomly assigns a hash to the files, causing problems with load balancing (sometimes the files aren't loading because the browser is requesting the hashed file name from server 1)

What is the best way to solve this?

One suggested way is to compile or build via gulp then dump the product into each server (perhaps Jenkins could help) but we are using a pretty OG way of deploying with Chef.

Comment: It's quite old, But I am facing it today, any suggestions on how to get it solved?